# Making IDs unique in HTML

Tags: php, html, variables, if-statement, unique-id

I'm such a noob at PHP. I'm really stuck on this and could do with some help!

I'm using the following code to control if a div class and span ID appears when a variable (e.g. $project1title and $project1description) is empty/not empty.

```
$html = '<div class="infobar"><div class="infobar-close"></div>';
$content = false;

if ($project1title !== '' && $project1description !== '')
{
$html .= '<span id="title"></span><span id="description"></span>';
$content = true;
}
// etc.

$html .= '</div>';

if ($content)
{
echo $html;
}
```

The code works fine when I've only got one project title & description there but when I start adding `($project2title !== '' && $project2description !== '') if ($project3title !== '' && $project3description !== '')`, etc it messes up because I need a unique ID for each project title & description. My question is, how can I make each of them have a unique ID? (Would I need to use arrays?) And once I've given each project a unique ID, where in the code above would I need to declare each unique ID?

Comment: Try to use `class` or `description_number` instead.

Comment: Why do you need it be in `id`, what is wrong with using a `class`?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the operations be:

```
!=
```

instead of

```
!==
```

?

Answer (score 0):

What about this :

```
<?php



$projects = array(
    array(
        'title' => 'myTitle',
        'description' => 'my description',
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'myTitle2',
        'description' => 'my description2',
    ),
);


$html = '<div class="infobar"><div class="infobar-close"></div>';
$content = false;


$id = 1;
foreach($projects as $project){
    if(!empty($project['title']) && !empty($project['description'])){
        $html .= '<span id="title'. $id .'"></span><span id="description'. $id .'"></span>';
        $content = true;
    }
    $id++;
}

$html .= '</div>';

if ($content) {
    echo $html;
}
```

Note that if id is important for you, you can add an id key in the projects array.
Does that help ?

Alternatively, I think you should take a look at dynamic vars :
here is simple example of what you can do with them :

```
<?php





$html = '<div class="infobar"><div class="infobar-close"></div>';
$content = false;




for($i = 1;$i<=10;$i++){
    $title = 'project' . $i . 'title';
    $description = 'project' . $i . 'description';

    if (isset($$title) && isset($$description) && $$title !== '' && $$description !== '')
    {
        $html .= '<span id="title'. $i .'"></span><span id="description'. $i .'"></span>';
        $content = true;
    }

}





$html .= '</div>';

if ($content)
{
    echo $html;
}
```